# How can I generate a list of latest check-in per project in TFS 2015?

Tags: sql, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to generate a list of Projects in TFS 2015 that are being actively worked on (so I know what teams to notify of planned downtime for an upgrade). There are almost 70 Projects so clicking through the history of each is a bit too labor-intensive.

I have seen examples for older versions of TFS that queried tbl_ChangeSet with a JOIN on tbl_identity, but that table is missing in my TFS 2015 database, and I can't locate a replacement.

**So my question is: how do I JOIN on OwnerId in tbl_ChangeSet in the TFS 2015 database?**

An example of a complete query that matches my objective is of course welcome too, as are any alternative methods (a PowerShell script maybe?)!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the tbl_Identity table!

In our company we have two TFS collections - let's call them FooBar and FooBar-DSG - with two corresponding databases: Tfs_FooBar and Tfs_FooBar-DSG.

The [tbl_Identity] table is in a database named Tfs_Foobar_Configuration.

To lookup records in the [tbl_Identity] table you will have to join [tbl_ChangeSet].[OwnerId] on [tbl_IdentityMap].[localId], and use [tbl_IdentityMap].[masterId] to join on [tbl_Identity].Id

Here's what I ended up with doing - not generating a list of teams but a list of users with their e-mail address and date of latest check-in. I can use this list to send my TFS downtime notification e-mail to.

Here are my queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [OwnerId], I.DisplayName, I.MailAddress,
    (SELECT TOP 1 CreationDate FROM [Tfs_FooBar-DSG].[dbo].tbl_ChangeSet C2 
     WHERE C2.OwnerId = C1.OwnerId ORDER BY CreationDate DESC) LatestDate
FROM [Tfs_FooBar-DSG].[dbo].[tbl_ChangeSet] C1
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Tfs_FooBar-DSG].[dbo].[tbl_IdentityMap] IM ON IM.[localId] = C1.OwnerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tfs_FooBar_Configuration.[dbo].[tbl_Identity] I ON IM.[masterId] = I.Id
ORDER By LatestDate DESC, [OwnerId], DisplayName, MailAddress

SELECT DISTINCT [OwnerId], I.DisplayName, I.MailAddress,
    (SELECT TOP 1 CreationDate FROM [Tfs_FooBar].[dbo].tbl_ChangeSet C2 
     WHERE C2.OwnerId = C1.OwnerId ORDER BY CreationDate DESC) LatestDate
FROM [Tfs_FooBar].[dbo].[tbl_ChangeSet] C1
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Tfs_FooBar].[dbo].[tbl_IdentityMap] IM ON IM.[localId] = C1.OwnerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tfs_FooBar_Configuration.[dbo].[tbl_Identity] I ON IM.[masterId] = I.Id
ORDER By LatestDate DESC, [OwnerId], DisplayName, MailAddress
```

**Update**: Daniel Mann warns in his comment below that "**You should not write queries directly against the TFS operational store. It is unsupported and potentially dangerous**". Decide for yourself if you can live with unsupported functionality, and how dangerous a SELECT query can be.

Comment: You should not write queries directly against the TFS operational store. It is unsupported and potentially dangerous.